# Can we use Autowiring byName and byType on same bean? if yes then how?

Tags: spring, autowired

I have tried autowiring byName and byType for different beans and it's working fine. But I want to use byName and byType autowiring on the same bean, can it be done? I have tried several way but it doesn't work.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="car" class="com.Car" autowire="byName">
        <property name="carName" value="BMW" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="wheel" class="com.Wheel">
        <property name="wheelType" value="with Tube" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="wheel1" class="com.Wheel">
        <property name="wheelType" value="tubeless" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="Byke" class="com.Byke" autowire="byType">
        <property name="bykeName" value="Honda" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="Wheel" class="com.Wheel">
        <property name="wheelType" value="No Information" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You can't autowire byType with this configuration because Spring won't know which bean to autowire if you define different beans on the same class.

Answer (score 1):

In short answer is **NO**. 
For explanation see the relevant API [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#createBean-java.lang.Class-int-boolean-) which clearly takes only one argument for type of autowiring you need viz. `autowireMode` 
For quick reference pasting signature - `java.lang.Object createBean(java.lang.Class<?> beanClass, int autowireMode ,boolean dependencyCheck) throws BeansException`